# importing folder containing PloneFormGen forms using quintagroup.transmogrifier

Tags: plone, ploneformgen, transmogrifier

I'm trying to migrate one folder that contains a lot of PloneFormGen folders from one plone instance to another. The export appears to go correctly based on what I can see from the tar ball and log file, but when I try to import said tarball into the new instance in portal_setup nothing is created and this is the only output I get:

```
2012-01-25 16:08:43 INFO GenericSetup.rolemap Role / permission map imported.
2012-01-25 16:08:45 INFO GenericSetup.archetypetool Archetype tool imported.
```

I'm migrating the folder from a Plone 4.0.2 instance to a Plone 4.1.3 instance on the same machine (CentOS 5.5/Python 2.6.6). The process I used is detailed in this [blog article](http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/12/27/importing-and-exporting-plone-folders-using-quintagroup-transmogrify/).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is coming in ridiculously late, but in the portal_setup/Import tab, did you select the quintagroup.transmogrifier profile in the dropdown at the top? I've also had problems importing and while I'm not sure if it's sufficient, I think it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you did not install quintagroup.transmogrifier in the second Plone Site as well.